# Spark Tachyon: How to delete a file?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, alluxio

In Scala, as an experiment I create a sequence file on Tachyon using Spark and read it back in. I want to delete the file from Tachyon using the Spark script also.

```
val rdd =  sc.parallelize(Array(("a",2), ("b",3), ("c",1)))
rdd.saveAsSequenceFile("tachyon://127.0.0.1:19998/files/123.sf2")
val rdd2 = sc.sequenceFile[String,Int]("tachyon://127.0.0.1:19998/files/123.sf2")
```

I don't understand the Scala language very well and I cannot find a reference about file path manipulation. I did find a way of somehow using Java in Scala to do this, but I cannot get it to work using Tachyon.

```
import java.io._
new File("tachyon://127.0.0.1:19998/files/123.sf2").delete()
```

Comment: I've had a similar problem, where I tried to clean up a file path after using it by deleting all the files I created. But for some reason it refused to delete all the files. Turns out it refused to delete the file if it was being used by a different process or program. That might be your problem here

Comment: You need to use the Tachyon API.

Answer (score -1):

There are different approaches, e.g.:

- CLI:

  ```
  ./bin/tachyon tfs rm filePath
  ```

More info: http://tachyon-project.org/Command-Line-Interface.html

- API:

  ```
  TachyonFS sTachyonClient = TachyonFS.get(args[0]);
  sTachyonClient.delete(filePath, true);
  ```

More info: 
https://github.com/amplab/tachyon/blob/master/core/src/main/java/tachyon/examples/BasicOperations.java